# UITableViewCell backgroundView not appearing on device

Tags: ios, uitableview, device, cell

I have a grouped table view and I have added a custom background view, I am setting these in code and all is well on the iOS simulator for normal and retina iPhone's, but on the device they don't show up at all, it's just a cell with no background at all.

I am doing the following:

```
UIImageView * imageview = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground.png"]] autorelease];
UIImageView * imageviewSelected = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackgroundSelected.png"]] autorelease];
[cell setBackgroundView:imageview];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:imageviewSelected];
```

Does anyone have a clue why this would not be working on the device ? I have deleted and reinstalled it, I cleaned the build folder and the the project but still no background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the image file name. Sometimes letter case matters. In simulator "Apple.png" and "apple.png" will work. But in device it wont.

Comment: That was it. As it worked alright in the simulator, I dismissed this possibility. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel. Glad to help you.I was bitten by it once.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this:

```
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Hello, didn't help out. It's very strange, almost like the images are not being sent to the device